# Create a copy of xml file in memory in java

Tags: java

I need to create a copy of an xml file in memory using java and i need to edit this file in memory without affecting the original one. After making changes to this xml in memory i need to send it as an input to a function. What is the appropriate option .Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use java native api for xml parsing:

```
DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
File file = new File("xml_file_name");
Document doc = builder.parse(file);
```

and then edit the Document in memory before sending it to your designated function.

Comment: If i do like this will other users be able to access the original copy at the same time in the same way?

Answer (score 0):

Do what you wrote:

1. Read the file.
2. Write it to another file.
3. Edit so called another file.
4. Pass it to the function. Here you have to decide if it's better to pass a file or a path.

Comment: that is not an option.Because mine is a multiuser case. Thats why i need this. If i make many copies of the same file in hard drive,that is not the appropriate way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is ByteArrayOutputStream. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html

This will allow you to write a byte array in to memory most xml lib will accept implementations of OutputStream.

Answer (score 0):

Given the file is XML you should consider using loading it into the Document Object Model (DOM): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/readingXML.html

That will make it easier for you to modify it and write it back as valid XML document.

I would only suggest loading it as bytes/characters if you're operating on it at a byte level. An example of when that might be appropriate is if you're making some character encoding translation (say UTF-16 -> UTF-8) or removing 'illegal' characters.

Code that tries to parse and modify XML in place usually becomes dreadfully bloated if it covers all valid XML files.

Unless you're a domain expert for XML, pick the parser of the shelf. It's pretty full of good libraries.

If the files may be large and your logic ameanable I would prefer to use an XML stream model such as SAX: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html

However I get the impression you're not experienced and non-experts tend to struggle with the event driven parsing model of SAX.

Try DOM first time out.

Comment: Actually, i am already using SAX for parsing my xml. The problem is if two or more users accesses the file simaltaneously it will create a problem. So i need to keep this xml file in memory when someone asks for it and leave the original file free for others to access, and i need to work with this copy in memory. parsing is not an issue. So, can u suggest some way to do this?

Comment: I see. That wasn't clear from the question. How about loading it into DOM? XML just isn't a structure that can be accessed concurrently with any ease. That would lead to implementing a Transaction Coordinator to marshall read/write operations on a file it directly controls.